# Ignore command / Suppress multiple spaces

Tags: spacing

How can I suppress multiple spaces in this example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{dummy foo output}
Test this \foo{3} command.
% but now I want to ignore it completely
\renewcommand*{\foo}[1]{\relax}
Test this \foo{3} command.
% ...and have no multiple spaces between "this" and "command"
\end{document}
```

I want to completely ignore `\foo` (still leaving it in the source code).

Kind regards, Ivan

Comment: Do you want it to run sometimes or only on certain compiles? If you only want it to be active on some compiles, you can just have multiple definitions in the preamble, and outcomment all the ones you don't want ;-)

Comment: I use such command through whole book, and on certain compiles I would like compiler to completely ignore it. I thought that defining it as `\relax` will do, but it produces two spaces (one before + one after).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The LaTeX kernel has `\@bsphack` and `\@esphack` for this.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\kokanignore}{\@bsphack\@esphack}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\newcommand*{\foo}[1]{dummy foo output}
Test this \foo{3} command.

\foo{3} xyz

% but now I want to ignore it completely
\renewcommand*{\foo}[1]{\kokanignore}
Test this \foo{3} command.
% ...and have no multiple spaces between "this" and "command"

\foo{3} xyz

\end{document}
```

[image]